Какие перспективы у слова "фиджитал" в русском языке?
Фиджитал — это phygital, от англ. physical + digital. В русском переводе: реальный и цифровой.
Как самостоятельное слово пока не нормировано, но в специализированных текстах оно встречается, например в такой статье:  "Мы живем в Матрице: что такое фиджитал, почему он уже победил, но этого еще никто не заметил".
Может ли слово войти в общелитературную лексику? Фонетика у него подходящая для сущ. мужского рода. Можно, к примеру,  образовать прилагательное: фиджиталовое мироощущение.

Все возможно, при том, что само явление не ново и развивается активно. Хотя сам термин не достаточно известен. Дело в том, вы и сами прекрасно знаете, словари русского языка не так часто издаются, поэтому, думаю, нужно ещё немного больше времени. Если термин станет достаточно популярным, он обязательно появится в словарях.

Спасибо,, Серж, за ответ.  Да, он должен стать популярным и понятным для людей.  А это не так просто — ведь по фонетике сложно определить его исходный смысл: phygital, от англ. physical + digital
